# Extracting Descriptors and feature points for 3d mesh

Tags: image-recognition, python, computer-vision, feature-extraction

I'm programming my work with python, and I have a mesh and I want to extract 3d descriptors and feature points from it( trying to work on multi-scale strategy) , to visualize them later on the mesh,

What I'm asking about, is references, guidelines, anything which could benefit me with this situation

The main work I'm trying to do, is to reach matching stage, where I could find one-to-one correspondence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work was done through the following:

1. Extract feature points using a Detector
2. Extract the descriptor for these feature points
3. Make matching using similarity measure between two descriptors from two meshes.